# Access a components objects

Tags: vue.js

How can I access the object that created a component? I have a timepicker and want to reference on in the other, so the second time can only be set after the first.

Let's say

```
<component></component>
<component></component>
```

With this code behind

```
var Comp = Vue.extend({  
  data: function() {
    return: { something: 'Hello'; }
  }
});
```

How can I access that variable **something** from outside the component? And how can I reference it in the *second* component?

Comment: You would have to save the data in a parent component and pass it to the child components as props.

Or use the store pattern: http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State-Management

Comment: This is what I did. Thanks.